# Equivalent to subquery without TOP or ORDER BY in HANA SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, hana

The SAP SQL Converter gave me this as output:

```
SELECT c."id", c."key_link", 
    (SELECT TOP 1 "notes_extra" 
    FROM "Orders" c2 
    WHERE c2."id" = c."id" AND c2."start" < c."start" 
    ORDER BY c2."start" DESC) AS "previous_notes" 
FROM "Orders" c
ORDER BY c."id";
```

Unfortunately, SAP HANA SPS 10 does not accept it:
**SAP DBTech JDBC: [309]: correlated subquery cannot have TOP or ORDER BY**

I am struggeling converting the query into something without TOP and ORDER BY. Tried a few things with `WHERE "start" = (SELECT MAX("start")` but since "start" can have duplicate values, I end up with: **SAP DBTech JDBC: [305]: single-row query returns more than one row**

So what's the correct equivalent in HANA SQL?

**Edit:**
 It seems to add to the problem that the column "notes_extra" is of type NCLOB. Any alternative I try to come up with ends at some point in an aggregate function (MAX, FIRST_VALUE, ...) on this column, which results in: **SAP DBTech JDBC: [264]: invalid datatype: LOB Type in aggregation func**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I don't care" is not something databases are good at handling. If there is no option to actually decide which row to take, then the data model simply is not fit to answer this question.

```
 select "id", "notes_extra" from 
     (SELECT c."id", c."notes_extra" 
            , row_number () over 
               (partition by c."id" 
                ORDER BY c."id" asc , c."start" desc) as RN 
      FROM orders c ) 
  where rn =2;
```

can deliver the 2nd last of the order comments based on the general sorting. Note that this delivers the same default tie-breaking behaviour as your initial query and that is: arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a sub-select at all, use a [window function](http://help.sap.com/hana_one/html/_esql_functions_window.html) instead:

```
SELECT c."id", c."key_link", 
       lag(c."notes_extra") over (partition by c."id" order by c."start" desc) as "previous_notes" 
FROM "Orders" c
ORDER BY c."id";
```

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately, in my case "notes_extra" isn't suitable for that: `SAP DBTech JDBC: [264]: invalid datatype: "C.notes_extra" LOB type of "previous_notes" cannot be used` - That also excludes all `GROUP BY "notes_extra"` approaches. :\

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the `FIRST_VALUE()` function for this, as in:

`SELECT (FIRST_VALUE(col ORDER BY col) FROM ... WHERE ...) AS ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you look only for the "first" column by a given sort order, you can always use the max()/min() aggregation. Not sure what problem you ran into, but that's definitively possible.
For your requirement I'd however recommend to implement the logic in a SQL view (and join this with your main query) or as a table udf.

Comment: `WHERE c2."start" = (SELECT MAX(c3."start") FROM "Orders" c3)` this could return multiple rows, because there are multiple rows with the same max "start" value, even when adding the other conditions. This resuts in an error message, because for the select list, only one result row must be returned. I added the error message in my original question.

Comment: Obviously you will need a tiebreaker for this. In case more than one records are returned, which one has to be taken?
If your initial code had worked, that would be undefined.

Comment: Lars: True. So how can I pick which one is taken, if I really don't care? See edit above.

Comment: "I don't care" is not something databases are good at handling. 
If there is no option to actually decide which row to take, then the data model simply is not fit to answer this question.
`select "id", "notes_extra"
from 
 (SELECT c."id", c."notes_extra"
 , row_number () over (partition by c."id" ORDER BY c."id" asc , c."start"  desc)  as RN
 FROM orders c  )
where rn =2;`
Can deliver the 2nd last of the order comments based on the general sorting. Note that this delivers the same default tie-breaking behavior as your initial query and that is: arbitrary.

Comment: Lars: That `row_number() over` approach actually works, thanks for the tip! I ended up optimizing the application to process all rows, not only "any first row", but your comment matches the initial question incl. all constraints best. Put it in an answer and it will be the selected one.